# Shortcut for Xcode Documentation Comments

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Is there an equivalent shortcut for a "Make Documentation Comment" like the one for regular comments - So it makes /// instead of //

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean, one that prepends /// instead of // to each selected line?

Comment: Did you search in Xcode preferences?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yes. That's what I meant. I looked there but didn't find anything suitable.

Comment: If the key binding for // is there but not for ///, I would abandon hope -at least for Xcode.

Comment: I think you might be able to achieve the same effect (not just for Xcode, but the whole Mac OS X) by creating a Service (with Automator or Xcode) that replaces selected text, and binding it (system wide, in System Preferences) to your favourite shortcut.

Comment: I'm not super versed on the details, but my comment above should provide you with enough search keywords to get it done.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. I will look into that. Meanwhile I will use the /***/ syntax.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Xcode 10 and later, place the cursor on a property or method and press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

You can see an example of this in [Paul Hudson](https://www.youtube.com/@twostraws)'s [Xcode in 20 Seconds: Adding documentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b_zF_xGnKw) video on YouTube.

Comment: Still, when adding more lines, we need to type '///' for each new line, gets annoying real fast. Maybe a code snippet for multiline '///' (thinking out laud).

Comment: @bauerMusic agree, having this comment wrapped into `/** ... */` will be much convenient

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode 14 the command changed slightly:

Placing the cursor over the symbol you want to document press the following command:
`CMD` + `OPTION` + `'`

Alternative you can go to "Editor" - "Structure" - "Add documentation"

[image: Xcode editor menu]